# What is the purpose of the "volatile" keyword appearing inside an array subscript?

Tags: c, arrays, volatile, function-parameter

While I was browsing cppreference, I saw a strange type array in function parameters like this:

```
void f(double x[volatile], const double y[volatile]);
```

So, What is the purpose of the `volatile` keyword appearing inside an array subscript? What does it do?

Comment: The target of that syntax is simply to make the code unreadable ;) Will add that to the "never do that" in our coding guidelines :-)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `volatile` keyword is used to declare an array type of a function parameter.

Here, `double x[volatile]` is equivalent to `double * volatile x`.

The [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/volatile) says :

> In a function declaration, **the keyword `volatile` may appear inside the
>   square brackets that are used to declare an array type of a function
>   parameter.** It qualifies the pointer type to which the array type is
>   transformed. The following two declarations declare the same function:
>
> ```
> void f(double x[volatile], const double y[volatile]);
>
> void f(double * volatile x, const double * volatile y);
> ```

This syntax only valid in C language in function parameters.

Comment: C++ syntax makes even less sense than I thought, I think we just hit a new high of uglyness. I hereby propose to ban alcohol from WG21 meetings.

Comment: @MatteoItalia That's not C++ syntax.

Comment: @hvd: my suggestion is then to be routed to WG14.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: C offers even more ugliness, since there's an exception to the rule: given `int foo(int myArray[static 5])`, the `static` qualifier does not mean the array is static, but rather guarantees that all of the storage from `myArray[0]`..`myArray[4]` may be presumed by the compiler to be readable without side-effects.

Comment: @supercat The guarantee is in fact that `x` pointers to an array element and the expressions `x[0]` through `x[4]` denote other elements of the same array (i.e. they do not read out of bounds of that array).  The term "side-effects" has a specific meaning in C

Comment: @supercat: my suspect is that the C committee was angry because C++ had one extra legal-but-completely-unrelated (ab)use of the `static` keyword (`static` methods), so they had to invent one for their language. Now I think we are even (local static-storage duration variables and internal-linkage variables being the other two, shared between C and C++).

Comment: @M.M: The C Standard doesn't really say what it means for an array of a particular type to exist in allocated storage.  If 32-byte block of memory from `calloc()` used as though it's a `float[]`, it should be possible to pass it to a function that expects a `uint32_t[static 8]` and populates some elements while ignoring others, even though at the time the pointer is passed no `uint_t[8]` would yet exist at that address unless one views allocated storage as a union of all possible types--a view that would have been workable under C89 but is broken by the "effective type" rule.

Answer (score 14):

In general, this C (and C only!) feature allows to specify any type qualifier inside the array brackets; the exact standard quotation is:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
>   type’’, **where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
>   array type derivation**. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the
>   array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding
>   actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many
>   elements as specified by the size expression.

(C99, §6.7.5.3, ¶7, emphasis added)

This means that this is not just limited to `volatile`, but `const` and `restrict` are allowed as well (see **Type qualifiers**, §6.7.3 ¶1).

The point of this hack is essentially to let you add a type qualifier *to the parameter* (**not** to the element of the array) and still retain the array syntax for the declaration; without this syntax, you are forced to fall back to writing it out as a pointer (which is what it boils down to anyway *except for the `static` case*, which AFAIK doesn't have an equivalent pointer syntax).

I suspect that the idea is mostly to make the syntax slightly less awkward for multidimensional arrays; quoting §6.7.5.3 ¶21:

```
void f(double (* restrict a)[5]);
void f(double a[restrict][5]);
void f(double a[restrict 3][5]);
```

are all equivalent, but 2 and 3 may convey slightly better that this is not intended just a pointer, but an array, and still allowing some place to put the `restrict` qualifier.

Also, as said above, there seem to be no way to have something like

```
void f(double a[restrict static 3][5]);
```

(which "also specifies that the argument corresponding to `a` in any call to `f` must be a non-null pointer to the first of at least three arrays of 5 doubles", *ibidem*) with the "regular" pointer syntax.

Still, I'd stay away from this syntax; it's extremely obscure, rarely used (I don't think I ever needed to add a type qualifier to an array *parameter* - again, the parameter itself, not the element type; `restrict` is the only use case that can make sense) - and not portable to C++ (which is generally relevant if you are writing a library).

Comment: If `volatile` can make sense in your code, this is quite useful.

Comment: @edmz: a `volatile` *parameter* is definitely bizarre... `volatile` means that the compiler should stay alert that the value stored there may change behind his back (due e.g. to interrupt handlers, signals or other hardware stuff); this is generally either stuff that is shared between multiple actors (e.g. some global variable) or something at a fixed location in memory known to the hardware/OS; a parameter instead is local to the function by definition, so I don't really get what kind of usefulness could `volatile` have here.

Comment: @edmz: (remember: `double x[volatile]` means `double * volatile x`, so it's `x` that is `volatile`, not what it points to)

Comment: @MatteoItalia: `modify_asynchronously(&a);`

Comment: @NateEldredge: copy it to a `volatile` local variable beforehand and use it instead.

Comment: *"and not portable to C++ (which is generally relevant if you are writing a library)"* - I'm sorry, but this argument is a non-starter IMO. Should a C++ library not use a well established practice of returning a unique_ptr "because C"? There's no harm in using C only features if your target is C exclusive.

Comment: @StoryTeller: *if your target is C exclusive* - which doesn't happen that often nowadays; being callable by other, higher level languages is a major selling point of C libraries (through FFI-like libraries or with straight header inclusion in case of C++). If you only care about the 13 or so C99 applications in the world good for you, but generally when I write C libraries I prefer to keep my API entrypoints low-tech and C++ friendly on purpose, especially since it's quite cheap. I even saw many C++ libraries provide a C89 API exactly for the sake of compatibility with the rest of the world.

Comment: That's why I said _"if `volatile` can make sense"_. Having, say, an interrupt-driven spin loop (waiting for an update of the address, like `NULL -> meaningful_addr`) will help you guard against the compiler which could turn it to `while (1)`. Naturally, I am _not_ saying this is everyday's meal - actually you might live without knowing about it as there're still alternatives  (you've pointed out one).